# Including a file in define directive in a makfile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile, definitions.mk, containing the following:

```
ifneq ($(MY_VARIABLE),true)
define my-function
  < some code defining the function)
endef
else
define my-function
 < different code defining the function>
endef
endif
```

Now, if MY_VARIABLE is set to false I want to include another file containing the definition of my-function. Like:

```
ifneq ($(MY_VARIABLE),true)
define my-function
  < some code defining the function)
endef
else
 <include file containing definition of function>
endif
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to do this include. If I write:

```
include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/my_function.mk
```

I will get an error saying:

```
/bin/bash/: include: command not found
```

So, how do I go about this?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Make are you using?

Answer (score 4):

**Actually, your second example should work just fine.**  Based on the error you're seeing I guess that although you have typed the code correctly here, what you *actually* have in your makefile is something like this:

```
ifneq ($(MY_VARIABLE),true)
define my-function
    thing1
    thing2
endef
else
define my-function
    include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/my_function.mk
endef
endif
```

That is, you have the `include` directive *inside* the `define` directive.  That won't work, because of the way `define` works.  Remember, `define` is just syntactic sugar to make it easier to create variables with multi-line values.  That means that, conceptually anyway, this:

```
define FOO
    something
endef
```

is the same as this:

```
FOO=something
```

So effectively what I suspect you've done is `my-function=include my_function.mk`.  Then when you try to reference `my-function`, it expands to `include my_function.mk`, which is subsequently passed off to the shell, which can't make sense out of it, of course.

**To be perfectly clear, here's how you can make this work.**  First, make sure you have the `define`/`endef` in my_function.mk:

```
define my-function
    red fish
    blue fish
endef
```

and then in definitions.mk you need to have this:

```
ifneq ($(MY_VARIABLE),true)
define my-function
    thing1
    thing2
endef
else
    include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/my_function.mk
endif
```

*Note the absence of the `define`/`endef` lines around the `include` line!*

Comment: What a great explanation Eric! Thank you so very much! I did have the define/endef in the wrong place. Thanks again.